# Is there a way to make a "sound" surveillance script?

Tags: sound, video, microphone, ffmpeg, sox

I'm looking a way to built something like a sound surveillance box.

I mean something that records audio/video on sound events captured by microphone.

For example it should record 5 seconds audio/video  before the first sound/noise  event and 5 seconds after the last sound/noise event.

This trick should run on raspberry then I'm looking for command line suggestion like ffmpeg, sox and so on.

Maybe I'll not find any integrated way to do that then it'll be enough that I can analyze 5 minutes of captured sounds and if true mux that with video otherwise if it's blank sound trash it.

Hope my question is enough clear.

Comment: Good trick record 5 seconds audio/video before, how would it ever know to start?

Comment: obviously it should always record and after detect sounds.

Comment: Imo, as this question is not really ubuntu-specific you might find better answers in other related stackexchange sites.

Comment: You might want to check e.g. this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406570/python-record-audio-on-detected-sound